# buttons not working in Python Tkinter code

Tags: python, button, tkinter

this is the part of the code in question,  its a bit messy but what happens is when i run the code only button1 can be used. the other buttons turn up and can be clicked but nothing happens. any idea what going on? im pretty sure it has something to do with the bind part but i cant fix it, it looks fine to me but it doesnt work so... haha thanks in advance

```
##Buttons##
    self.button1 = Button(self.canvays)
    self.button1.configure(text="Pride", background="red")
    self.button1.pack(side=RIGHT)
    self.button1.focus_force()
    self.button1.place(x=85, y=367)
    self.button1.bind("<Button-1>", self.button1Click)

    self.button2 = Button(self.canvays)
    self.button2.configure(text="Murder", background="blue")
    self.button2.pack(side=TOP)
    self.button2.focus_force()
    self.button2.place(x=225, y=367)
    self.button2.bind("<Button-2>", self.button2Click)

    self.button3 = Button(self.canvays)
    self.button3.configure(text="Lions", background="Yellow")
    self.button3.pack(side=TOP)
    self.button3.focus_force()
    self.button3.place(x=380, y=367)
    self.button3.bind("<Button-3>", self.button3Click)



    self.root.mainloop()

def incorrect(self):
    self.labelincorrect = Label(text = "Sorry that wasnt right, try again")
    self.labelincorrect.pack(side=TOP)
    self.labelincorrect.place(x=250, y=250)
def correct(self):
    self.score = self.score+1

##Button Event##

def button3Click(self, event):
    self.incorrect()
def button2Click(self, event):
    self.incorrect()
def button1Click(self, event):
    self.root.destroy()
    self.correct()
    Question2()
```

Comment: Are you aware that you're binding the mouse wheel button to `button2`, and right-click to `button3`? If you want normal behavior, you don't have to bind anything to buttons at all. They behave like buttons by default. Please see a tutorial on Tkinter for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.button2.bind("<Button-2>", self.button2Click)
```

`<Button-2>` refers to the mouse button that this event will respond to, not the name of your widget. This button will only respond to middle clicks.

If you want each button to respond only to left clicks, bind each of them to `<Button-1>`.

You can also specify onclick behavior by using the `command` named argument in the button's initializer:

```
self.button1 = Button(self.canvays, command=button1Click)
```

... Although if you do this, you won't have access to the `event` value in the function.